# Website forms glitching out and background cover won't cover screen when zoomed out in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, web

My website is http://www.clinkstr.com and I have 2 forms on the front page. When I zoomed all the way out in Chrome, the forms and the background will move down a lot. Can someone look at my CSS and HTML code and see if I did something wrong? And also, in IE, background-size: cover won't cover the entire screen when zooming in or out.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have absolutely positioned them making them not apart of the flow.